# Hi pls how to display the child menu only to the sidebar, this is the code but all are appearing in displaying

Tags: php

Code to display:

```
<?php
    $sql= "SELECT DISTINCT locations FROM location ORDER BY parent";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) ;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-lable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input   producy_check" value="<?= $row['locations']; ?>" id="locations"><?= $row['locations']; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php }  ?>
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `location` (`id`, `locations`, `parent`) VALUES
(1, 'Colombo', 0),
(2, 'Gampaha', 0),
(3, 'Kandy', 0),
(4, 'Kurunegala', 0),
(5, 'Kalutara', 0),
(6, 'Ratnapura', 0),
..............continue.....
(26, 'Col 01 - 15', 1),
(27, 'Dehiwala', 1),
(28, 'Homagama', 1),
(29, 'kaduwela', 1),
(30, 'Kesbewa', 1),
(31, 'Kolonnawa', 1),
(32, 'Kotte', 1),
(33, 'Maharagama', 1),
(34, 'Moratuwa', 1),
(35, 'Padukka', 1),
(36, 'Ratmalana', 1),
(37, 'Seethawaka', 1),
(38, 'Thimbirigasyaya', 1),
(39, 'Gampaha', 2),
(40, 'Attanagalla', 2),
(41, 'Biyagama', 2),
(42, 'Divulapitiya', 2),
(43, 'Dompe', 2),
(44, 'Ja-Ela', 2),
(45, 'Katana', 2),
```

Expected : I want the child 1 to the side bar but everything is coming to display in my coding.

```
(26, 'Col 01 - 15', 1),
(27, 'Dehiwala', 1),
(28, 'Homagama', 1),
(29, 'kaduwela', 1),
```

Comment: first of all create a parent-child array and then iterator over it and create your desired html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.
First is you could add to the SQL “WHERE parent=1”, what will get you all items where the parent = 1.

Section option would be to put an if statement in to say to only display if the parent = 1.

```
if ($row[‘parent’] == 1){
    ...
}
```

If this was me, I’d probably use the first method:

```
<?php
    $sql= "SELECT DISTINCT locations FROM location WHERE parent=1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) ;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-lable">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input   product_check" value="<?= $row['locations']; ?>" id="locations"><?= $row['locations']; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php }  ?>
```

Side note, I noticed a spelling mistake in the classes for your input, “producy_check” rather than “product_class”

Comment: excellent thanks bro